# After the whole deck runs through, the cards disappear. Where in my for loop(s) or arraylist(s) should change so they don't disappear?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, 2d-games, playing-cards

After I run through the game (52 turns), the cards disappear. However, the code that makes the game run still works, but I just can't see the cards drawn.

I've tried looking through my code debugging, and looking through the classes as well as previous assignments but nothing seems to work. Sorry, first post and I'm not sure how to format and I could also provide more code if needed

```
ArrayList<Cards> cards = new ArrayList<Cards>();
ArrayList<Deck1> deck1 = new ArrayList<Deck1>();
ArrayList<Deck2> deck2 = new ArrayList<Deck2>();
ArrayList<Play> play = new ArrayList<Play>(); // the cards played
```

// dividing the cards into two decks randomly

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * (51 - i) + 0);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            deck1.add(new Deck1(cards.get(j).getFile(), cards.get(j).getPV()));
            cards.remove(j);
            f.add(deck1.get(b).getIcon());
            b++;
        } else if (i % 2 == 1) {
            deck2.add(new Deck2(cards.get(j).getFile(), cards.get(j).getPV()));
            cards.remove(j);
            f.add(deck2.get(a).getIcon());
            a++;
        }
    }
```

I want the game to work and have all the cards show up for as long the game needs to be until it has finished. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
int j = (int) (Math.random() * (51 - i) + 0);
```

The problem is that `Math.random()` generates a number in the range 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive), so `j <= 50 - i`, meaning you'll never pick the last card in the deck.

Change 51 to 52.

Or, easier:

```
int j = (int) (Math.random() * cards.size());
```

Or less repetitively:

```
Cards card = cards.remove((int) (Math.random() * cards.size()));
```

Now just use `card` instead repeating `cards.get(j)` and `cards.remove(j)`.

(And note that your `Cards` class should be called `Card`, probably).

Or, easier again:

```
Collections.shuffle(cards);
deck1.addAll(cards.subList(0, cards.size() / 2));
deck2.addAll(cards.subList(cards.size() / 2, cards.size()));
```

(although you would have to then somehow alternate the cards into `f`).

Comment: Or perhaps `random.nextInt(cards.size())`, where `random` is either a `new Random()` or a `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`.